# Filter pandas with operator chain from list

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm having a pandas table which contains some columns:

```
col_list = list('ABC')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=col_list)

    A   B   C
0   8   5   7
1   5   4   1
2   7   5   6
3   6   6   0
4   3   4   1
```

and I have a list of thresholds according to which I want to filter df:

```
thr = [3, 6, 9]
```

Is there a ways to filter `df` in each column according to the relevant threshold in `thr`, so that

```
new_df = df[(df['A']>thr[0]) & (df['B']>thr[1]) & (df['C']>thr[2]) )
```

without explicitly write it using list comprehension of operators, something like

`not_sure = [df.iloc[:, [i]]>thr[i] for i in range(3)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with boolean mask created by `np.all`:

```
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  5  8  10
1  5  4   1
2  7  5   6
3  6  6   0
4  3  4   1

thr = [3, 6, 9]

df = df[np.all(df.values > np.array(thr), axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  5  8  10
```

Pandas solution with [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) `(>)` with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = df[df.gt(thr).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  5  8  10
```

And solution with list comaprehension:

```
masks = [df.iloc[:, i] > j for i, j in enumerate(thr)]
df = df[pd.concat(masks, axis=1).all(axis=1)]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(masks)]
```

---

**Explanation**:

First compare all values by `np.array` - is necessary same lengths of `thr` and columns:

```
print (df.values > np.array(thr))
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [False False False]]
```

Then check all `True`s per rows by [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
print (np.all(df.values > np.array(thr), axis=1))
[ True False False False False]
```

Comment: I probably would have gone for the pandas one... but as well as the list comp for completeness you could have: `df[functools.reduce(operator.and_, (df.iloc[:, i] > v for i, v in enumerate(thr)))]`

Comment: @JonClements - Yes, or use numpy alternative `df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(masks)]`, thank you.

Comment: Yes - much nicer :)